# Ext JS doesn't load on import, response body is 0bytes in FireBug

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

For starters I'm brand new to ExtJS

Thanks for taking a moment to look at my problem, so far I haven't been able to find any equivalent questions anywhere. I'm attempting to transition a webapp interface from Tiles/Spring/jQuery to a Tiles/Spring/ExtJS interface, but I'm having trouble in getting some of the basics started.

For starters, the code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var login = new Ext.FormPanel({
        title: "Please Login",
        url: 'j_spring_security_check',
        labelWidth: 80,
        frame: true,
        defaultType: 'textField',
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
        monitorValid: true,
        bodyStyle: 'padding:10px',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Username',
            name: 'j_username',
            id: 'userName',
            allowBlank: false,
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function(field) {
                    field.focus();
                }
            }
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            name: 'j_password',
            inputType: 'password',
            allowBlank: false
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Login',
            formBind: true,
            handler: function() {
                loginSubmit();
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Reset',
            formBind: true,
            handler: function() {
                reset();
            }
        }],
        listeners: {
            afterRender: function(thisForm, options) {
                this.keyNav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', this.el, {
                    enter: loginSubmit,
                    scope: this
                });
            }
        }
    });

    function reset() {
        login.getForm().reset();
    }

    function loginSubmit() {
        login.getForm().submit({
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(form, action) {
                window.location = 'home';
            },
            failure: function(form, action) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Login Failed!', 'Login Failed');
                reset();
            }
        });
    }

    login.render('login');
});
```

And this is wrapped properly in the script tags, in a jsp page.

I import the extJS files in the tile page that this JSP renders to:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

And at this point I'd expect things to render somehow, but instead I get this:
[image: firebug error]

Strangely, the files do load successfully (at least they don't appear with an error) except that it shows a responseBody of 0 bytes, as you can see in lines 2 and 3 below.
[image: firebug response]

I've looked around and already tried all the easy fixes to the best of my ability, I'm hoping someone here will be able to help. Thanks again for taking the time to look at my problem.

### Update

When I changed out the script reference to the sencha CDN, I get past this error on to a new one, but I want to stick with this and resolve this first.

My best guess now based on the comments below is that I'm either missing ext-base.js (which is not included in the ExtJS I have downloaded) or I somehow have my file location/Spring config wrong. I've added these entries to my spring config now:

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/extjs/*" mapping="/extjs/**" />
 ....
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/appName/extjs/**"
  access="permitAll" requires-channel="any" />
```

And yet I still have the same error. I've got the extjs folder in my WEB-INF directory, shouldn't that mvc:resources above fix that so I can reference it like so:

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"
```

Yet I still get the "302 found" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the network traffic history (your latest image), extjs files (ext-all-debug.js and ext-all.css) are not found. What is more interesting is that the error code is a 302 (probably a redirection) instead of the more common 404.

Anyway, that´s the reason you get a 0-bytes response, because the resource is not there. You could see the failing requests details in order to see more details but basically you should verify the files location and your server/application configuration to see why those files couldn´t be found.

**Update:**

This kind of problems are, most of the times, because you are not authenticated. Then, when you do a GET request the server checks you are not authenticated and then it redirects you (302 error code) to the login page.

Using the CDN works because you don´t have to be authenticated on the CDN server!

The login page has to have access to all the resource it needs even when you are not authenticated.

Sadly, I don´t know the technology you are using but that´s the problem you are suffering.

Comment: you may be right. I just reloaded the page with a link to the sencha CDN ext-all and it got me past that error at least. I'm looking at my webAppContext xml now (Spring) to see if I missed something.

Comment: Where might I see more from the request details? It doesn't seem like firebug offers much detail beyond http header information. Thanks again for your suggestion, I updated the original question  with some of the lines I added to the Spring config

Comment: I'm thinking you're on the right track here and it has to do with Authentication. The project uses Spring to manage this so I probably just need to update some part of my xml config to accommodate the directory. I wasn't the one who worked on this portion of the Spring set up, so I must have just missed the obvious!

Comment: Yep it was a spring config problem, hadn't set up the paths to be allowed before authentication. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing this one... ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
```

The path may be wrong, you may have to correct that

**UPDATE**

The ext-base.js was not needed, and indeed it can't be found anywhere. Check your code to see if all of these are included

I'll just post the head of my index.php

```
<head>

    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">

    <title>Page Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/views/css/data-view.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I've seen a reference to ext-base.js elsewhere, but it didn't seem to come with my current copy of ExtJS (4.1.1) so I figured that was deprecated. Is this not the case? I didn't see a reference to ext-base in the getting started or other guides.

Comment: Yep, you're right... my bad.
 ext-base.js is not needed.
The times I got that Ext is not a function I was missing some file include, like the one I suggested. I'll paste my index.php from one of my projects so you can check all of the files are included in yours too

Comment: Thanks for posting the excerpt from your index file. I double checked my imports and I  do have all of those, except I haven't built out an app.js as I'm really just trying to build a simple panel/container with ExtJS at the moment. I appreciate your suggestions.